# Object tag to transparent mode

Tags: jquery, object, transparent, wmode

A simple question,

How to detect all `<object>` tag in the dom and add `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` or change its 'wmode' to transparent using jquery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery code like this will attempt to change the parameter.

```
$('object').each(function(index, elem) {
    var wmode = elem.children('param[name="wmode"]');
    if(!wmode.length) {
        elem.append('<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>');
    } else {
        wmode.attr('wmode', 'transparent');
    }
});
```

However, this will not achieve the desired effect; you need to completely delete and recreate the object for the change to actually take effect. (I've tried, in the past, temporarily removing and then re-adding the object tag, without *cross-browser* success.) You may want to look at the SWFObject library. There's even [a jQuery plugin for it](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/).

Comment: +1 for noting that this probably isn't going to work in IE. From my past experience, IE will not listen to changes in `object` tags. To get around this, I have tried, with varying success, to remove the `object` element completely and create and insert a new element with your desired properties.